# .htaccess Preappending PHP File That Contains Paths

Tags: php, .htaccess, include, include-path

I'd like to preappend a php file using the .htaccess file. This I know how to do.

```
# Prepend file.php
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/file.php"
```

Things get a little tricky because file.php has an include.

```
include("assets/something.php");
```

Will this pose an issue for pages that are in subdirectories? Is there a failproof way to write the path so it'll still work no matter where file.php is being preappended?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always make my includes absolute, rather than relative:

```
include(__DIR__ . "/assets/something.php");
```

This solves the issue that you don't know where a file might be included from. The entry point is used as the base for relative paths rather than the file you're currently in.